# Prove equality by Catalan number

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I try to prove equality $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}^2 = {2n\choose n}$$ by using a relation of Catalan number $$C_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}C_{k-1}C_{n-k}.$$
After substituting $$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n},$$ and some derivations, I arrive at $${2n\choose n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k(2k-2)!(2n-2k)!(n+1)}{(n-k+1)(n-k)!^2k!^2},$$ so I need to show $$\frac{k(2k-2)!(2n-2k)!(n+1)}{n-k+1} = n!^2.$$
Now I'm having trouble doing this step and I was wondering if there is something wrong with my previous steps.

Comment: In the third equation ... the $k$ is in the wrong place
\begin{eqnarray*}
{2n\choose n} = \sum_{\color{red}{k=1}}^{n} \frac{(2k-2)!(2n-2k)!(n+1)}{\color{red}{k} (n-k+1)(n-k)!^2k!^2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You will not get there none of the terms $(n+1)C_{k-1}C_{n-k}$ is equal to one of the terms $\left(\matrix{n \\ k}\right)^2$.I have tried for n=7.